# Що означає слово "цьма"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

У вірші Д. Павличка ["Ностальгія"](http://poetyka.uazone.net/default/pages.phtml?place=pavlychko&page=nostal01) натрапила на таке слово:

> Хахли-манкурти — плем’я безголове,
>
> Та не кажіть, що розуму нема
>
> У тих створінь, бо до чужої мови
>
> Вони летять, немов до лампи **цьма**;

У [CУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/cjma) цього слова немає.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У [Словнику лемківської говірки](https://ukrainian_lemko.academic.ru/14841/%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0) знаходимо:

> **цьма**
>   -цьми, ж. Пр.
>   1. Мряка, темнота. 
>   2. Нетля; невеликий нічний метелик. 
>   - Цьма літат вночи.

У [Словнику галицької говірки](http://halmova.if.ua/dictionary/letter/26/) знаходимо:

> **Цьма** - міль.

У [Лексиконі львівському](https://ukr-lviv.sesii.net/7895-%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0) також знаходимо:

> цьма нічний метелик (ср, ст)||бомок.

Отже, "вони летять, немов до лампи нічний метелик".

Comment: Зауважу лиш що в наших краях немає нічних метеликів, тож перекладати потрібно тільки як "міль", до того ж велика. На малу міль цьма (тьма) не кажуть. Ну а бомок (бомко) - це ґедзь і я ніколи не чув щоб хто- чи коли-небудь на них казав цьма.